# Upload artifact nexus with security credentials rsa ssh

Tags: maven, ssh, deployment, nexus, sonatype

I referred to [sonatype](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/appendix-settings-sect-details.html). 
Below service configuration in settings.xml do not work. Is it `${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa or ${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa?` 
What seem could be wrong because the ssh host for passphrase keeps on prompting?

```
<server>
<id>server001</id>
<username>my_login</username>
<password>my_password</password
<privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
<passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
<filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
<directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
<configuration></configuration>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Maven or Nexus from all I know.